# CAS Single Sign Out requests being ignored by JSP+Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, single-sign-on, cas

I've set up CAS for single sign on with my Spring+JSP webapp, but now I've found out that single sign out isn't actually logging me out of the applications. I've confirmed that if I go to the CAS logout page, I do receive a SAMLP logout request from CAS. When I go back to a secured page in the app, however, I get in without logging back in to CAS. If I go to the local app logout page (`/j_spring_security_logout`), then I will get logged out and immediately redirected to the CAS login page.

In a nutshell, it appears that the local app isn't registering the logout request from CAS and calling its own logout procedure.

Here's the CAS portion of my **web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>authenticationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Ticket Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>ticketValidationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Ticket Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Do I need a specific CAS bean created to handle logouts in my applicationContext.xml files? Or is configured completely through the web.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

When you debug the SingleSignOutFilter does it invalidate the user session? Maybe the CAS Token is being held in it, or in the SecurityContextHolder so it doesn't ask for a new login. I have a similar issue and am sorry to not be able to fully understand SS + CAS.